# Cascade groupby/transform operations

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a set of groups and subgroups, with dates and values.

What I need in the end is to evaluate a rolling mean, with window 2, of the values by month by group (the value for the current month is evaluated using the past 2 months).

I can achieve that If I reduce the dataframe by two consecutive groupbys:

- the first to evaluate the sum of values for each group (groupby
  group|date, sum)
- the second to evaluate the monthly rolling mean by
  group (groupby group|month, transform, rolling)

But this reduces my data.

What I need is to do it it all using transform operations, so I could get my results as a column on the original dataframe.

Lets take a look on this dummy data:

```
values = [100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300]
dates = ['2017-01-01', '2017-02-01',
         '2018-01-01', '2018-02-01',
         '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'value': values})
df1['subgroup'] = 'subgroup1'

df2 = df1.copy()
df2['subgroup'] = 'subgroup2'
df2['value'] = df2.value *2

df_g1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)

df_g1['group'] = 'group1'

df_g2 = df_g1.copy()
df_g2['group'] = 'group2'
df_g2['value'] = df_g2.value *2

df = pd.concat([df_g1, df_g2], axis=0)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

Now the first groupby operation:

```
df_total_by_group = df.groupby(['group', 'date'], as_index=False)[['value']].sum()
df_total_by_group['month'] = df_total_by_group['date'].dt.month
```

Now the rolling mean:

```
def rolling_mean(serie):
    return serie.shift(1).rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean()

df_total_by_group['month_rolling_mean_by_group'] = (df_total_by_group
                                                    .groupby(['group', 'month'])['value']
                                                    .transform(rolling_mean)
                                                   )

# display results
df_total_by_group.sort_values(by=['group', 'month'])
```

[image]

I'm getting the right results here,
but I needed them as a column in the original dataframe.

I'm lost here. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with list of columns - here `on` is missing, because merge by intersecion of all common columns of both DataFrames:

```
df = df.merge(df_total_by_group[['group','date','month_rolling_mean_by_group']], how='left')
```

So it working same like:

```
df = df.merge(df_total_by_group[['group','date','month_rolling_mean_by_group']], 
              how='left',
              on=['group','date'])

print (df)
         date  value   subgroup   group  month_rolling_mean_by_group
0  2017-01-01    100  subgroup1  group1                          NaN
1  2017-01-01    200  subgroup2  group1                          NaN
2  2017-02-01    100  subgroup1  group1                          NaN
3  2017-02-01    200  subgroup2  group1                          NaN
4  2018-01-01    200  subgroup1  group1                        300.0
5  2018-01-01    400  subgroup2  group1                        300.0
6  2018-02-01    200  subgroup1  group1                        300.0
7  2018-02-01    400  subgroup2  group1                        300.0
8  2019-01-01    300  subgroup1  group1                        450.0
9  2019-01-01    600  subgroup2  group1                        450.0
10 2019-02-01    300  subgroup1  group1                        450.0
11 2019-02-01    600  subgroup2  group1                        450.0
12 2017-01-01    200  subgroup1  group2                          NaN
13 2017-01-01    400  subgroup2  group2                          NaN
14 2017-02-01    200  subgroup1  group2                          NaN
15 2017-02-01    400  subgroup2  group2                          NaN
16 2018-01-01    400  subgroup1  group2                        600.0
17 2018-01-01    800  subgroup2  group2                        600.0
18 2018-02-01    400  subgroup1  group2                        600.0
19 2018-02-01    800  subgroup2  group2                        600.0
20 2019-01-01    600  subgroup1  group2                        900.0
21 2019-01-01   1200  subgroup2  group2                        900.0
22 2019-02-01    600  subgroup1  group2                        900.0
23 2019-02-01   1200  subgroup2  group2                        900.0
```

If use `transform` for first `sum` it working differently:

```
df['value'] = df.groupby(['group', 'date'], as_index=False)['value'].transform('sum')
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month


def rolling_mean(serie):
    return serie.shift(1).rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean()

df['month_rolling_mean_by_group'] = (df.groupby(['group', 'month'])['value']
                                        .transform(rolling_mean))
```

---

```
print (df)
        date  value   subgroup   group  month  month_rolling_mean_by_group
0 2017-01-01    300  subgroup1  group1      1                          NaN
1 2017-02-01    300  subgroup1  group1      2                          NaN
2 2018-01-01    600  subgroup1  group1      1                        300.0
3 2018-02-01    600  subgroup1  group1      2                        300.0
4 2019-01-01    900  subgroup1  group1      1                        450.0
5 2019-02-01    900  subgroup1  group1      2                        450.0
0 2017-01-01    300  subgroup2  group1      1                        750.0
1 2017-02-01    300  subgroup2  group1      2                        750.0
2 2018-01-01    600  subgroup2  group1      1                        600.0
3 2018-02-01    600  subgroup2  group1      2                        600.0
4 2019-01-01    900  subgroup2  group1      1                        450.0
5 2019-02-01    900  subgroup2  group1      2                        450.0
0 2017-01-01    600  subgroup1  group2      1                          NaN
1 2017-02-01    600  subgroup1  group2      2                          NaN
2 2018-01-01   1200  subgroup1  group2      1                        600.0
3 2018-02-01   1200  subgroup1  group2      2                        600.0
4 2019-01-01   1800  subgroup1  group2      1                        900.0
5 2019-02-01   1800  subgroup1  group2      2                        900.0
0 2017-01-01    600  subgroup2  group2      1                       1500.0
1 2017-02-01    600  subgroup2  group2      2                       1500.0
2 2018-01-01   1200  subgroup2  group2      1                       1200.0
3 2018-02-01   1200  subgroup2  group2      2                       1200.0
4 2019-01-01   1800  subgroup2  group2      1                        900.0
5 2019-02-01   1800  subgroup2  group2      2                        900.0
```

Answer (score 1):

What I've been doing is creating a new data frame for my aggregates and then joining back to the original data frame.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['group, 'date'], how='left')
```

Comment: on must be ['group, 'date']

Comment: I think of it as the "newb" way to do it lol - also edited to include date